# Pathname modified with IE

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, iis, pathname

I have a web site in IIS. When I open it with FireFox I have my path name like this :

http://WebSiteName/ControllerName/ViewName

So in IE 10 I have a string add between web site name and controller name :

WebSiteName/ (F(tXsULdieggBmidgAHhBWIArSZGI2xTHXKFUmtUdW5_3o3hUeInshtdta4A7JUWV13w6_HbIoXQOg3Q3NHJcIX5_TYPCZIg5LecfxTOYMCec1))/ControllerName/ViewName

I don't understand this, any help would be appreciated!

thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That looks like asp.net session data when you have set the `Session Cookie Settings Mode` to `Use URI`, in your web.config check for:

```
<system.web>
    <sessionState cookieless="UseUri" />
</system.web>
```

when using this setting, the session data is embedded in the url, rather than a cookie. It's normally not recommended to do this.

In theory it should behave the same way in Firefox.